# Lazy initialization for stack objects?

Tags: c++, stack, declaration

I know we can do the following with heap objects:

```
/* Heap objects */
Pet *pet;

if (...)
    pet = new Pet("Dog");
else
    pet = new Pet("Cat");
```

But how do we do it if we wanted the `Pet` object to be declared on the stack?

```
/* Stack objects */
Pet pet;

if (...)
    -?-
else
    -?-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
Pet pet(theCondition ? "Dog" : "Cat");
```

Or if the conditional blocks are more complex than a single initialization store the `const char*` which is used for initialization as a separate local

```
const char* pArgument;
if (...) {
  ...
  pArgument = "Dog";
} else {
  ...
  pArgument = "Cat";
}

Pet pet(pArgument);
```

Comment: But if it is a more complex if-else statement?

Comment: @LeifEricson just added a more complex version a sec ago

Answer (score 3):

```
string param;
if (...)
   param = "Dog"
else 
   param = "Cat";

Pet pet(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

The lazy initialization obviously needs to be done by the base object itself.

```
if (...)
    animal.Initialize("Dog");
else
    animal.Initialize("Cat");
```

This doesn't work if the object has virtual methods that need to be filled in by derived classes - in that case the pointer is the only workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your class supports default construction and copy assignment, the following would work:

```
Pet pet;  //- assumes Pet class supports default construction.

if (theCondition)
{
    pet = Pet("Dog");  //- assumes Pet class supports copy assignment.
}
else
{
    pet = Pet("Cat");
}
```

Of course, you'll have to pay for two constructions and a copy for the privilege of putting your pet on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

[boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) can be used to get lazy initialization (even for containers):

```
boost::optional<Animal> d;
if(foo) d = Animal("Dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant have the same with stack objects.

However, here are some alternatives:

```
/* Stack objects */

if (...)
{
  Animal animal("Cat");
  ...
}
else
{
  Animal animal("Dog");
  ...
}
```

or not so lazy

```
Animal cat("Cat");
Animal dog("Dog");
Animal *animal;

if (...)
{
  animal = &cat;
}
else
{
  animal = &dog;
}
```

Comment: Your first solution is not good because those objects won't exist outside the if-else.

Comment: Ok, but you did not ask that.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use functions, or in C++11, lambdas:

```
auto returnArg = [&]() -> const char * {
    if (...) return "Dog";
    else return "Cat";
};

Animal animal(returnArg());
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the loading of the stack into 2 steps.

```
void doTheThingToTheAnimal(Animal& animal) {
  ...
}


// select the animal
if (...) {
  Animal animal("Dog");
  doTheThingToTheAnimal(animal);
} else {
  Animal animal("Cat");
  doTheThingToTheAnimal(animal); 
}
```